# Failure in torsion

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics, mechanical-failure

Why does a ductile rod in torsion fail at an angle perpendicular to its axis? I know the reason for brittle material failing in pure shear but I don't understand the reason for ductile material.

Comment: materials are rarely 100% ductile

Comment: ok but assuming it is.Can you give me the theoritical answer?

Comment: Do a Mohr's circle and note the direction of the principal stresses. They are 45° from the axis of the rod (90° on Mohr's circle).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a rule of thumb:
When brittle materials are subjected to torsion they fail in the plane, where tension is at its highest, i.e. at a 45° angle.
Ductile materials on the other hand fail in the plane of maximum shear stress.

Take a look at Mohr's Circle for pure shear.

[image: Mohr's Circle for pure shear]

*Maximum-Shear-Stress Theory* states:

> [...] yielding of the [ductile] material begins when the absolute maximum shear stress in the material reaches the shear stress that causes the same material to yield when it is subjected *only* to axial tension.
> – *R.C. Hibbeler, Mechanics of Materials, p.525*

for ductile materials: $$ \tau_{max}=\frac{\sigma_y}{2} $$
As you can see in the graphic, $\tau_{max}$ is reached before $\sigma_y$, thus the plane of failure is perpendicular to the primary axis.

For brittle materials on the other hand, *Maximum-Normal-Stress Theory* says:

> [...] a brittle material will fail when the maximum tensile stress, $\sigma_1$, in the material reaches a value that is equal to the ultimate normal stress the material can sustain […]
> – *R.C. Hibbeler, Mechanics of Materials, p.528*

for brittle materials: $$ \tau_f=\sigma_f $$
So, under pure shear it fails in tension at a 45° angle.

Answer (score 0):

The stresses of a rod in shear and in torsion are of the same kind. So they fail of the same reason.

There is a conversion factor for materials. It is sqrt(3). So with the same stress induced to a rod under torsion compared to one under tensile load is more likely to break by this factor.